grpc connection not working from jar file, DomainSocketAddress cannot be cast to class java.net.InetSocketAddress
I'm trying to make a grpc server and client, using the example from the github repo. It works fine when I run the Main.kt from IntelliJ, however when I build the jar file and run that, it throws upon connection immediately with the following error:
SEVERE: [Channel<1>: (localhost:50053)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.netty.channel.unix.DomainSocketAddress cannot be cast to class java.net.InetSocketAddress (io.netty.channel.unix.DomainSocketAddress is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.net.InetSocketAddress is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder$OkHttpTransportFactory.newClientTransport(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:842)
    at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:59)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:254)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:94)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:126)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:959)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:901)
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1$1.invokeSuspend(ClientCalls.kt:276)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1$1.invoke(ClientCalls.kt)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1$1.invoke(ClientCalls.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:264)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1.invokeSuspend(ClientCalls.kt:274)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1.invoke(ClientCalls.kt)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1.invoke(ClientCalls.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230)

This is the jar-related part of my build.gradle.kts:
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    // Otherwise you'll get a "No main manifest attribute" error
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "ginf.appcore.MainKt"
    }

    // To avoid the duplicate handling strategy error
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    // To add all of the dependencies
    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}

